# How return query output back to shell script?

Tags: shell, ant

I am invoking ant from shell script.
Ant in turn invokes java to run a SQL query.
Query returns a flag value, either 0 or 1.

How to return query output (0/1) back to shell script?

Answer (score 1):

You can return value from the java to the ant using the `outputproperty` as @VirtualTroll presented. Then in ant I would write the variable to the temporary file:

```
<java jar="..." outputproperty="output"/>
<echo file="/tmp/query_result">${output}</echo>
```

Now in the bash script you should first check the error code of the ant and the existence of the file and then read the content.

Answer (score 0):

The [java task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/java.html) from  ant has a special parameter "**outputproperty**" to capture the output of the java task.

You only need to set the parameter in your java task

```
 <java jar="..." outputproperty="output"/>
 <echo>The output is ${output}</echo>
```

Then you can do whatever you want with the parameter value.

Comment: User is triggering Ant from shell, and wants output back in shell

Answer (score 0):

In your **ANT** file, configure the `java` task to write output to property called `output`. Then, if the value of `output` is **not** `0` we can `FAIL` the build, and pass value of `output` to shell. Else, the build will be `SUCCESS` and pass `0` to shell.

```
<java jar="..." outputproperty="output"/>
<!-- Exit with non-zero exit code -->
<fail message="Output returned non-zero" status="${output}">
    <condition>
        <not>
            <matches pattern="0" string="{output}"/>
        </not>      
    </condition>
</fail>
<!-- Else ANT exits with 0 exit code -->
```

Now in your **SHELL** script, capture the exit code with `$?`

```
# Your ANT execution
ant -f build.xml 
# Capture exit code into variable $exitcode
exitcode=$?
# Decide what to do with $exitcode
if [ $exitcode -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "ANT returned with 0"
else
    echo "ANT returned with $exitcode"
fi
```

Comment: We are trying same logic what you explained above. But we don't want to use <fail> because it will fail the build. Is there any other of way doing it? Our code looks as belwo:  <fail message="${error.message}" status="${queryOutput}">
<condition>
<equals arg1="${intvalue}" arg2="${check.flag.unavailable.value}" />
</condition>
</fail>

Comment: If you want to use `exitcode`, to be captured by shell through `$?`, then `<fail/>` is the only option that will manipulate ANT exitcode, however as you said, this will mark build as `failed`. If that's unacceptable, then Boris's solution of writing to a file is what you need, but then you have to read and parse the file from within Shell